# WPF/C# Drag and Drop from a ListView onto Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have a ListView with a custom view for displaying items as icons.  I also have a regular ol' canvas.  I want to be able to drag an item from the ListView and drop it into the canvas.

Now I've looked all over the place for various tutorials on how to do Drag and Drop.  It seems like everything I've found either doesn't work at all or does way more than I need.  Hooking up the Drop event on the Canvas and calling DoDragDrop in the PreviewMouseMove event on the ListView seems to not work.  I start dragging, I get the DragEnter/DragOver on the Canvas but the drop event is never fired (the cursor remains as a (/))

I've looked into a bunch of other solutions such as the DragDrop library or the Drag Drop Smorgasbord on CodeProject.  These seem to be designed to remove the actual item from the control and place the control somewhere else.  This isn't what I need, all I need is to detect a drop on the Canvas from the ListView, pass along some data (right now its just a string) and use that data to build a new UIElement in the Canvas.

Is there a simpler approach than using DoDragDrop?  I'd like to be able to still have Adorners and such, but it seems like some of the solutions out there would be way more work than I should have to do and wouldn't exactly do what I need anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the  **AllowDrop="True"** property on the canvas ?!? 
Your first solution looks neat and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thread creator here...made the post with an unregistered account, but registered because this place is cool!  I figured out my problem.  Turns out I was setting the Effects in the DragEnter/DragOver to something I shouldn't have.

Now I feel silly.

Thanks for the reply though!